# Symfony, FosUserBundle with console and GEDMO - Blameable

Tags: symfony, command, fosuserbundle

I got somethink like this in my entity class:

```
    /**
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="update")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FoSUserSomeeWhere:)")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="updated_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $updatedBy;
```

and I want to update this entity without logging - why? Because I need to do this by using console command. Allready build a service. Is there any know solution for that? Meyby some default user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove listener.

```
<?php

    $listenerInst = null;
    $evm = $em->getEventManager();
    foreach ($evm->getListeners() as $listeners) {
        foreach ($listeners as $listener) {
            if ($listener instanceof \Gedmo\Blameable\BlameableListener) {
                $listenerInst = $listener;
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($listenerInst) {
        $evm->removeEventListener(array('onFlush'), $listenerInst);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable *Blameable* filter.

```php
<?php

// This will disable filter (adapt the filter name with your configuration)
$em->getFilters()->disable('blameable');

/* Your code with entity manager flush */

// This will enable filter
$em->getFilters()->enable('blameable');
```